# Ubuntu distribution for a Notebook?

Tags: xubuntu, hardware, lts

My soundcard stopped suddenly working on my Xubuntu LTS 14.04.

Is it better to install the most recent stable Xubuntu version on a Notebook? Is LTS only suggested for servers?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes most recent version works better, or just works while older version can't work at all on some computers. LTS is a stable release. LTS is recommended for usage (no matter laptop or server). LTS is not specially for servers. Latest LTS is 14.04. You should try to use 15.04 (it is not LTS). Non-LTS releases are less stable than LTS, but they are pretty good.

Comment: Non-LTS releases fall out of support in 18 months, while LTS versions are supported for five years. If you don't want to commit to a full system upgrade every year-and-a-half, the latest LTS release is the best bet for most people.